# What is the best way to declare a service in a feature module?

Tags: angular

It seems the default for services is:

```
@Injectable(
    {
    providedIn: 'root'
}
)
```

Which is intended to place the service in 'root' ... which is a special string that in this case refers to app.module or whatever you've named your root module. You can change this to your module name, but this means you need to import the module and that always seems to lead to a circular dependency error (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170). You can declare it the old fashioned way in the 'providers' array, but this doesn't seem to work for me. This leads me back to 'root', but it appears that there is an order of declarations issue, in which the service is uninstantiated in the child component. At this point, is there a single path for this use-case, or is it still being decided?

Comment: May you prepare a [mcve] that shows the problem of uninstantiated service in child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Service should be used only inside your feature module you can also provide it in the module

For Instance

```
import { MyModule } from ' ./my.module';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: MyModule;
})
```

providing it in 'root' makes the service available to components/services of the whole application.

Comment: Your module can also define a service used internally and not provided outside. Let's say a "private" service that shall not be used outside your module